# Algorithm to find the days between two dates

Tags: java, algorithm

I was working with a school question to figure out the algorithm to find the days between two given dates which would then be implemented in Java.

The algorithm of interest was found here:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/datediffindays/calcdiffofdatesindates.html
(Point 4)

It was one of the more efficient algorithms because it would have the least conditions to consider during the implementation. I understand how it works in this context, but I couldn't quite wrap my mind around the use of an origin/reference point anywhere else because it seems that a simple subtraction would get most jobs done.

Eg. To find the difference between 9 and 5,
I could just do `9-5` instead of

`ref = 1`

`difference = (9-ref) - (5-ref)`

Question: Why does using this reference/origin point work in this situation? What other situations can I consider using this reference/origin point to solve problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule of Software Engineering is "Don't reinvent the wheel".

Getting the days between two dates in Java 8 and later is trivial, there's no need to code your own algorithm:

```
    LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(1950, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    long days = d1.until(d2,ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Or even better

```
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely my go-to if I want to implement them fast. But I believe my school is trying to help us to understand "the best way to make a wheel" so we can appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get difference between 9-th and 5-th day of the same month, you can just subtract 9-5 *(if there was no calendar revolution in that period :))*. But for different months and different years you must account for varying number of days in the month and varying number of days in the year.

The simplest way to account for these factors is to get absolute number of days from some origin day - so-named [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) with our era beginning as origin

Comment: Are there any other problems where I can make use of this reference/origin points as an effective solution? I understand dates have this complexity (difference months, leap years) so this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `9-5` uses a reference of `0` in the same way as `(9-0) - (5-0)`.

Unlike numbers, where `0` is the reference point, for dates, the reference point is not obvious. Should it be 0 AD, 1900 AD, or something else? With the different number of days in months, leap years etc, the day scale is not uniform. So, it is useful to find the "distance" of a date from a common date, for e.g. 1970-01-01.